# XML CDATA Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I am trying to build an XML document in C# with CDATA to hold the text inside an element. For example..

```
<email>
<![CDATA[test@test.com]]>
</email>
```

However, when I get the InnerXml property of the document, the CDATA has been reformatted so the InnerXml string looks like the below which fails.

```
<email>
&lt;![CDATA[test@test.com]]&gt;
</email>
```

How can I keep the original format when accessing the string of the XML?

Cheers

Comment: Please show how you're building the document. I suspect you're just setting the text node to "<![CDATA[test@test.com]]>" which is why it's being escaped.

Comment: Indeed I am... using the InnerText property of the XmlNode.

What should I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `InnerText`: use [`XmlDocument.CreateCDataSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
        XmlElement email = doc.CreateElement("email");
        XmlNode cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection("test@test.com");

        doc.AppendChild(root);
        root.AppendChild(email);
        email.AppendChild(cdata);

        Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! I was having the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

With `XmlDocument`:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement email = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("email"));
    email.AppendChild(doc.CreateCDataSection("test@test.com"));
    string xml = doc.OuterXml;
```

or with `XElement`:

```
    XElement email = new XElement("email", new XCData("test@test.com"));
    string xml = email.ToString();
```

Comment: The new X* classes rule! XCData is even nice enough to break up strings into multiple CDATA elements that would break it (the only reserved sequence inside one: "]]>"). For example: `new XCData("]]>blah")` outputs `<![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>blah]]>`, with "]]" in one CDATA element and the ">" in another.

Answer (score 1):

See [XmlDocument::CreateCDataSection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx)  for information and examples how to create CDATA nodes in an XML Document